# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.base Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, import, kivy

I have ran sudo apt-get install python3-kivy but when i try to run a python file that uses kivy I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.base'; 'kivy' is not a package.
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be? I am running Ubuntu Mate 18.04

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""

FloatLayout:

    Button:

        text:'B1'

        size_hint_x: 0.3

        size_hint_y: 0.9

"""))
```

Comment: Try installing via pip.

Comment: i tried pip install kivy python 3 as well

Comment: Kivy is not installed in the python environment you are attempting to run python from. It isn't possible to be sure why this is, because you haven't given the full details, but if you're doing something like `python yourfile.py` it could be because `python` calls python2 and not the python3 you installed Kivy to.

Comment: I have tried python3 milefile.py and it still does not work

Comment: What other details should I provide?

Comment: *"What other details should I provide?"* Show the **path** where `python3-kivy` got installed. Check it **this path** is within `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: when i ran system path in the terminal i get this message ['', '/home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']